# Fortran argument must be Allocatable in Python F2PY

Tags: python, fortran, allocation, f2py

I am currently trying to compile Fortran scripts in the Python command terminal into Python modules using the numpy.f2py function as displayed below:

```
python -m numpy.f2py -c  -m matching_pairs Matching_Pairs_V2.F90 --fcompiler=gnu95 --compiler=mingw32
```

It works fine for two other Fortran scripts and I am able to import them in Python. However, when I run this code command for this specific file I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\web200\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpst9o9who\src.win-amd64-3.9\matching_pairs-f2pywrappers2.f90:48:64:

      &, frame_sint_cutoff, lambda_min, s0_vector, motion_angle, mask, se&
                                                                1
Error: Actual argument for 'mask' must be ALLOCATABLE at (1)
```

After searching through the script I found the subroutine I think is causing the error:

```
! Filtering of monorays
      subroutine frame_windows_filtering(mono_rays, mono_rays_len, TransMatrix, frame_sint_cutoff, lambda_min, S0_vector,&
     motion_angle, mask, selected_transformed_mono_rays)

         ! Input/Output variables
         REAL*8, INTENT(IN) :: frame_sint_cutoff, lambda_min
         REAL*8, DIMENSION(:,:), INTENT(IN) :: mono_rays
         REAL*8, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: mono_rays_len
         REAL*8, DIMENSION(3,3), INTENT(IN) :: TransMatrix
         REAL*8, DIMENSION(3), INTENT(IN) :: S0_vector
         REAL*8, INTENT(IN) :: motion_angle

         REAL*8, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE, INTENT(OUT) :: selected_transformed_mono_rays
         LOGICAL,DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE, INTENT(OUT) :: mask

         REAL*8:: max_h_len, Theta, cos_min, cos_max
         REAL*8, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: transformed_mono_rays
         REAL*8,DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: normalized_transformed_mono_rays
         REAL*8,DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: transformed_mono_rays_normes
         REAL*8, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: cos_angles
         LOGICAL,DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: mask_max_h_len, mask_max_coords, mask_min_coords
         INTEGER :: mono_rays_size, i, selection_size

         ! Max h len max
         max_h_len = 2.0 * frame_sint_cutoff/lambda_min

         ! Perform transformation on monorays
         mono_rays_size = size(mono_rays_len)
         ALLOCATE(transformed_mono_rays(mono_rays_size,3))
         ALLOCATE(normalized_transformed_mono_rays(mono_rays_size,3))
         ALLOCATE(transformed_mono_rays_normes(mono_rays_size))
         ALLOCATE(cos_angles(mono_rays_size))
         ALLOCATE(mask_max_h_len(mono_rays_size))
         ALLOCATE(mask_max_coords(mono_rays_size))
         ALLOCATE(mask_min_coords(mono_rays_size))
         IF (ALLOCATED(mask)) THEN
           DEALLOCATE(mask)
         END IF
         ALLOCATE(mask(mono_rays_size))
         transformed_mono_rays=matmul(mono_rays,transpose(TransMatrix))
         transformed_mono_rays_normes = sqrt(sum(transformed_mono_rays**2,2))

         ! Normalize transformed monorays
         DO i = 1, 3
            normalized_transformed_mono_rays(:,i) = transformed_mono_rays(:,i)/transformed_mono_rays_normes
         END DO

         ! Cos limits
         Theta = dasin(frame_sint_cutoff)
         cos_max = dsin(motion_angle)
         cos_min = -dsin(motion_angle+Theta)

         cos_angles = MATMUL(normalized_transformed_mono_rays,S0_vector)
         ! Filtering of mono rays per frame considering ranges of coordinates
         ! Filtering of mono rays 
         mask_max_h_len = (mono_rays_len .le. max_h_len)
         ! Max coordinates filtering
         mask_max_coords = (cos_angles <= cos_max)
         ! Min coordinates filtering
         mask_min_coords = (cos_angles >= cos_min)

         ! Total mask
         mask = mask_max_h_len.and.mask_max_coords.and.mask_min_coords
         selection_size = count(mask .eqv..True.)
         IF (ALLOCATED(selected_transformed_mono_rays)) THEN
            DEALLOCATE(selected_transformed_mono_rays)
         END IF
         ALLOCATE(selected_transformed_mono_rays(selection_size,3))

         ! Indices of monoray vectors, normalized monoray vectors
         !return mask, normalized_transformed_mono_rays(mask,:)
         selected_transformed_mono_rays = RESHAPE(PACK(normalized_transformed_mono_rays, SPREAD(mask,2,3)), (/selection_size,3/))

         DEALLOCATE(transformed_mono_rays)
         DEALLOCATE(normalized_transformed_mono_rays)
         DEALLOCATE(transformed_mono_rays_normes)
         DEALLOCATE(cos_angles)
         DEALLOCATE(mask_max_h_len)
         DEALLOCATE(mask_max_coords)
         DEALLOCATE(mask_min_coords)
      end subroutine frame_windows_filtering
```

I am not fluent in Fortran so I am not sure how I fix this. Naively to me it looks like the "mask" variable is already allocatable.

### Edits

Thank you for your quick and insightful responses. The original Fortran script was quite long so I've provided a minimised version below that still replicates the original error. The subroutine matching_per_frame calls the subroutine frame_windows_filtering using the variable 'frame_mono_rays_mask' in place of the 'mask' variable which is seemingly causing the error.

The variable 'frame_mono_rays_mask' doesn't have the INTENT(OUT) argument attached to it but the 'mask' variable does. Apart from that they seem the same.

For anyone who is interested in the original source code, it can be found at http://sourceforge.net/projects/laueutil/ in the source_fortran_module folder and the script is labelled Matching_Pairs.F90.

```
  MODULE matching_pairs

  ! All Subroutines must be public to build a PYTHON/FORTRAN module
  ! using F2PY command
  IMPLICIT NONE
  PUBLIC :: matching_per_frame
  PUBLIC :: frame_windows_filtering
  PUBLIC :: quicksort

  CONTAINS

  ! matching_per_frame:
  ! - Optimize motion angle and shape angle limits
  ! - Identify normalized H-vectors with unique neighbouring mono ray
  !
  ! Input parameters
  ! mono_rays             : Monochromatic rays
  ! mono_rays_len         : Normes of monochromatic rays
  ! unit_expts      : Normalized expts prefiltered (maxsint, I_limit)
  ! unit_expts_I    : Intensities of normalized expts
  ! unit_expts_sint : Sintheta of normalized expts
  ! S0_vector : S0 vector in goniometer basis
  ! TransMatrix           : Transformation matrix
  ! g_min_I          : Global minimal I
  ! g_motion_ang   : Global crystal motion angle
  ! g_shape_ang    : Global cell shape angle
  ! min_I_step            : Minimal I step
  ! motion_ang_step     : Crystal motion angle step
  ! shape_ang_step      : Cell shape angle step
  ! frame_sint_cutoff       : Max sintheta cutoff
  ! lambda_min            : Minimal possible lambda
  ! nb_expt_pairs     : Expected Number of (expt, monoray) pairs
  ! nb_mono_rays          : Number of monochromatic rays
  ! nb_unit_expts   : Number of normalized expts
  ! Output parameters
  ! final_array_unique_pair_indices : Identified (expt, monoray) pairs
  ! l_min_I           : Frame intensity limit
  ! best_l_motion_ang : Frame crystal motion angle limit
  ! best_l_shape_ang  : Frame cell shape angle limit

  SUBROUTINE matching_per_frame (mono_rays, mono_rays_len, &
  unit_expts, unit_expts_I, unit_expts_sint, S0_vector, &
  TransMatrix, g_min_I, g_motion_ang, &
  g_shape_ang, min_I_step, motion_ang_step, &
  shape_ang_step, lambda_min, nb_expt_pairs, &
  nb_mono_rays,nb_unit_expts,final_array_unique_pair_indices, &
  l_min_I, best_l_motion_ang, best_l_shape_ang, nb_matched_pairs)

     ! Input/Output variables
     REAL*8, INTENT(IN) :: g_min_I, g_motion_ang, g_shape_ang
     REAL*8, INTENT(IN) :: min_I_step, motion_ang_step, shape_ang_step
     REAL*8, INTENT(IN) :: lambda_min
     INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: nb_expt_pairs, nb_unit_expts, nb_mono_rays
     REAL*8, DIMENSION(nb_unit_expts,3), INTENT(IN) :: unit_expts
     REAL*8, DIMENSION(nb_unit_expts), INTENT(IN) :: unit_expts_I, unit_expts_sint
     REAL*8, DIMENSION(3), INTENT(IN) :: S0_vector
     REAL*8, DIMENSION(nb_mono_rays,3), INTENT(IN) :: mono_rays
     REAL*8, DIMENSION(nb_mono_rays), INTENT(IN) :: mono_rays_len
     REAL*8, DIMENSION(3,3), INTENT(IN) :: TransMatrix

     INTEGER,DIMENSION(nb_expt_pairs,2), INTENT(OUT) :: final_array_unique_pair_indices
     REAL*8, INTENT(OUT) :: l_min_I, best_l_motion_ang, best_l_shape_ang
     INTEGER, INTENT(OUT) :: nb_matched_pairs

     ! Local variables
     REAL*8 :: frame_sint_cutoff ! Cutoff sint applied on monorays
     REAL*8 :: rounded_g_min_I, rounded_g_motion_ang, rounded_g_shape_ang ! Rounded limit values
     REAL*8, DIMENSION(nb_unit_expts) :: sorted_unit_expts_I ! Sorted intensity array of unit vectors
     REAL*8, PARAMETER :: deg2rad = 0.017453292519943295d0
     INTEGER, DIMENSION(nb_unit_expts) :: unit_expts_indices
     INTEGER, DIMENSION(nb_mono_rays) :: mono_rays_indices
     INTEGER :: nb_motion_ang_steps, nb_shape_ang_steps
     REAL*8, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: motion_ang_range, shape_ang_range
     INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: frame_mono_rays_indices
     INTEGER :: I_limit_indice, nb_filtered_expts
     REAL*8 :: I_limit
     LOGICAL,DIMENSION(nb_unit_expts)::I_limit_mask
     REAL*8, DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE::filtered_unit_expts_I, filtered_unit_expts_sint
     REAL*8, DIMENSION(:,:),ALLOCATABLE :: filtered_unit_expts
     INTEGER,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE::filtered_unit_expts_indices
     LOGICAL,DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: frame_mono_rays_mask
     REAL*8, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: frame_mono_rays
     REAL*8,DIMENSION(:,:),ALLOCATABLE :: cos_delta_angles_monos_expts
     LOGICAL, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: cos_delta_angles_monos_expts_mask
     INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: array_nb_neighbours
     INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: filtered_array_nb_neighbours
     INTEGER :: i

     ! Check extremum values specified in input 
     rounded_g_min_I = min_I_step*FLOOR(g_min_I/min_I_step)

     ! Definition of crystal motion angle range
     nb_motion_ang_steps = CEILING(g_motion_ang/motion_ang_step)
     rounded_g_motion_ang = motion_ang_step * float(nb_motion_ang_steps)

     IF (ALLOCATED(motion_ang_range)) THEN
        DEALLOCATE(motion_ang_range)
     END IF

     ALLOCATE(motion_ang_range(nb_motion_ang_steps))

     DO i = 1, nb_motion_ang_steps
        motion_ang_range(i) = float(i) * motion_ang_step
     END DO

     ! Definition of cell shape angle range
     nb_shape_ang_steps = CEILING(g_shape_ang/shape_ang_step)
     rounded_g_shape_ang = shape_ang_step * float(nb_shape_ang_steps)

     IF (ALLOCATED(shape_ang_range)) THEN
        DEALLOCATE(shape_ang_range)
     END IF

     ALLOCATE(shape_ang_range(nb_shape_ang_steps))

     DO i = 1, nb_shape_ang_steps
        shape_ang_range(i) = float(i) * shape_ang_step
     END DO

     ! Initialisation of array of expt global indices before filtering
     ! Global indices of unit expts 

     DO i = 1, nb_unit_expts
        unit_expts_indices(i) = i
     END DO
     ! Global indices of mono rays 
     DO i = 1, nb_mono_rays
        mono_rays_indices(i) = i
     END DO

    
     ! Selection of the largest intensity unit expts
     ! The expected number of pairs is smaller than the number of expt vectors

     IF (nb_expt_pairs .le. nb_unit_expts) THEN 
        ! Sorting of intensity of normalized expt vectors in increasing order
        sorted_unit_expts_I = unit_expts_I
        call quicksort(sorted_unit_expts_I, unit_expts_indices)
        I_limit_indice = nb_unit_expts - nb_expt_pairs + 1
        I_limit = sorted_unit_expts_I (I_limit_indice)
        ! Round the intensity limit
        l_min_I = dmax1(min_I_step*FLOOR(I_limit/min_I_step), rounded_g_min_I)
        I_limit_mask = unit_expts_I .ge. l_min_I
     ELSE

        sorted_unit_expts_I = unit_expts_I
        call quicksort(sorted_unit_expts_I, unit_expts_indices)
        I_limit_mask = unit_expts_I .ge. rounded_g_min_I
        l_min_I = rounded_g_min_I
     END IF

     ! Selection of the first Nbexpectedpairs expts with the largest intensities
     nb_filtered_expts = min(COUNT(I_limit_mask .eqv. .True.), nb_expt_pairs)

     ! Allocation of arrays
     IF (ALLOCATED(filtered_unit_expts_I)) THEN
        DEALLOCATE(filtered_unit_expts_I)
     END IF

     ALLOCATE(filtered_unit_expts_I(nb_filtered_expts))
     IF (ALLOCATED(filtered_unit_expts_sint)) THEN
        DEALLOCATE(filtered_unit_expts_sint)
     END IF

     IF (ALLOCATED(filtered_unit_expts_sint)) THEN
        DEALLOCATE(filtered_unit_expts_sint)
     END IF

     ALLOCATE(filtered_unit_expts_sint(nb_filtered_expts))
     IF (ALLOCATED(filtered_unit_expts_indices)) THEN
        DEALLOCATE(filtered_unit_expts_indices)
     END IF

     ALLOCATE(filtered_unit_expts_indices(nb_filtered_expts))
     IF (ALLOCATED(filtered_unit_expts)) THEN
        DEALLOCATE(filtered_unit_expts)
     END IF

     ALLOCATE(filtered_unit_expts(nb_filtered_expts,3))

     ! Filtering of unit expts according to the intensity threshold
     filtered_unit_expts_I = sorted_unit_expts_I (nb_unit_expts-nb_filtered_expts+1:)
     filtered_unit_expts_sint = unit_expts_sint (unit_expts_indices(nb_unit_expts-nb_filtered_expts+1:))
  
     filtered_unit_expts_indices = unit_expts_indices(nb_unit_expts-nb_filtered_expts+1:)

     filtered_unit_expts = unit_expts(filtered_unit_expts_indices,:)

     ! If there is no expt vectors

     IF (nb_filtered_expts == 0) THEN
        final_array_unique_pair_indices = 0
        best_l_motion_ang = 0.0
        best_l_shape_ang = 0.0
        nb_matched_pairs = 0
        return
     END IF

     ! Selection of mono rays
     ! Max sin(theta) value
     frame_sint_cutoff = maxval(filtered_unit_expts_sint)

     ! Selection of monorays in normalized H-vector coordinate ranges by filtering
     call frame_windows_filtering(mono_rays, mono_rays_len, &
  TransMatrix, frame_sint_cutoff, lambda_min, S0_vector, &
  rounded_g_motion_ang, frame_mono_rays_mask, frame_mono_rays)
   
     ! Deallocate memory
     IF (ALLOCATED(motion_ang_range)) THEN
        DEALLOCATE(motion_ang_range)
     END IF
     IF (ALLOCATED(shape_ang_range)) THEN
        DEALLOCATE(shape_ang_range)
     END IF
     IF (ALLOCATED(array_nb_neighbours)) THEN
        DEALLOCATE(array_nb_neighbours)
     END IF
     IF (ALLOCATED(filtered_array_nb_neighbours)) THEN
        DEALLOCATE(filtered_array_nb_neighbours)
     END IF
     IF (ALLOCATED(filtered_unit_expts_I)) THEN
        DEALLOCATE(filtered_unit_expts_I)
     END IF
     IF (ALLOCATED(filtered_unit_expts_sint)) THEN
        DEALLOCATE(filtered_unit_expts_sint)
     END IF
     IF (ALLOCATED(filtered_unit_expts_indices)) THEN
        DEALLOCATE(filtered_unit_expts_indices)
     END IF
     IF (ALLOCATED(filtered_unit_expts)) THEN
        DEALLOCATE(filtered_unit_expts)
     END IF
     IF (ALLOCATED(frame_mono_rays_indices)) THEN
        DEALLOCATE(frame_mono_rays_indices)
     END IF
     IF (ALLOCATED(cos_delta_angles_monos_expts)) THEN
        DEALLOCATE(cos_delta_angles_monos_expts)
     END IF
     IF (ALLOCATED(cos_delta_angles_monos_expts_mask)) THEN
        DEALLOCATE(cos_delta_angles_monos_expts_mask)
     END IF
     IF (ALLOCATED(frame_mono_rays_mask)) THEN
        DEALLOCATE(frame_mono_rays_mask)
     END IF
     IF (ALLOCATED(frame_mono_rays)) THEN
        DEALLOCATE(frame_mono_rays)
     END IF
     return

  END SUBROUTINE matching_per_frame

  ! Filtering of monorays
  subroutine frame_windows_filtering(mono_rays, mono_rays_len, &
  TransMatrix, frame_sint_cutoff, lambda_min, S0_vector, &
  motion_angle, mask, selected_transformed_mono_rays)

     ! Input/Output variables
     REAL*8, INTENT(IN) :: frame_sint_cutoff, lambda_min
     REAL*8, DIMENSION(:,:), INTENT(IN) :: mono_rays
     REAL*8, DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN) :: mono_rays_len
     REAL*8, DIMENSION(3,3), INTENT(IN) :: TransMatrix
     REAL*8, DIMENSION(3), INTENT(IN) :: S0_vector
     REAL*8, INTENT(IN) :: motion_angle

     REAL*8, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE, INTENT(OUT) :: &
  selected_transformed_mono_rays
     LOGICAL,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE, INTENT(OUT) :: mask

     REAL*8:: max_h_len, Theta, cos_min, cos_max
     REAL*8, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: transformed_mono_rays
     REAL*8,DIMENSION(:,:),ALLOCATABLE :: &
  normalized_transformed_mono_rays
     REAL*8,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE :: transformed_mono_rays_normes
     REAL*8, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: cos_angles
     LOGICAL,DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE :: mask_max_h_len, &
  mask_max_coords, mask_min_coords
     INTEGER :: mono_rays_size, i, selection_size

     ! Max h len max
     max_h_len = 2.0 * frame_sint_cutoff/lambda_min

     ! Perform transformation on monorays
     mono_rays_size = size(mono_rays_len)
     ALLOCATE(transformed_mono_rays(mono_rays_size,3))
     ALLOCATE(normalized_transformed_mono_rays(mono_rays_size,3))
     ALLOCATE(transformed_mono_rays_normes(mono_rays_size))
     ALLOCATE(cos_angles(mono_rays_size))
     ALLOCATE(mask_max_h_len(mono_rays_size))
     ALLOCATE(mask_max_coords(mono_rays_size))
     ALLOCATE(mask_min_coords(mono_rays_size))
     IF (ALLOCATED(mask)) THEN
        DEALLOCATE(mask)
     END IF
     ALLOCATE(mask(mono_rays_size))
     transformed_mono_rays=matmul(mono_rays,transpose(TransMatrix))
     transformed_mono_rays_normes = &
  sqrt(sum(transformed_mono_rays**2,2))

     ! Normalize transformed monorays
     DO i = 1, 3
        normalized_transformed_mono_rays(:,i) = &
  transformed_mono_rays(:,i)/transformed_mono_rays_normes
     END DO

     ! Cos limits
     Theta = dasin(frame_sint_cutoff)
     cos_max = dsin(motion_angle)
     cos_min = -dsin(motion_angle+Theta)

     cos_angles = MATMUL(normalized_transformed_mono_rays,S0_vector)
     ! Filtering of mono rays per frame considering ranges of coordinates
     ! Filtering of mono rays 
     mask_max_h_len = (mono_rays_len .le. max_h_len)
     ! Max coordinates filtering
     mask_max_coords = (cos_angles <= cos_max)
     ! Min coordinates filtering
     mask_min_coords = (cos_angles >= cos_min)

     ! Total mask
     mask = mask_max_h_len.and.mask_max_coords.and.mask_min_coords
     selection_size = count(mask .eqv..True.)
     IF (ALLOCATED(selected_transformed_mono_rays)) THEN
        DEALLOCATE(selected_transformed_mono_rays)
     END IF
     ALLOCATE(selected_transformed_mono_rays(selection_size,3))

     ! Indices of monoray vectors, normalized monoray vectors
     !return mask, normalized_transformed_mono_rays(mask,:)
     selected_transformed_mono_rays = RESHAPE( &
  PACK(normalized_transformed_mono_rays, SPREAD(mask,2,3)), & 
  (/selection_size,3/))

     DEALLOCATE(transformed_mono_rays)
     DEALLOCATE(normalized_transformed_mono_rays)
     DEALLOCATE(transformed_mono_rays_normes)
     DEALLOCATE(cos_angles)
     DEALLOCATE(mask_max_h_len)
     DEALLOCATE(mask_max_coords)
     DEALLOCATE(mask_min_coords)

  end subroutine frame_windows_filtering

  ! quicksort: Recursive subroutine which sorts all values from a 1D-array in increasing order 
  recursive subroutine quicksort(Values, Indices)
     REAL*8, intent(inout), dimension(:) :: Values
     INTEGER, intent(inout), dimension(:) :: Indices
     integer :: MarkerIndex

     ! If the size of A is 1, no need to sort
     IF (size(Values) .gt. 1) THEN
        ! Partition selects a threshold value, sorts values
        ! to put all values smaller than this threshold before
        ! and to put all values larger than this threshold after
        call partition(Values, Indices, MarkerIndex)
        ! quicksort is applied on the first part [1:IndexOfThreshold] of the array (all values smaller than the threshold)
        call quicksort(Values(:MarkerIndex-1),&
  Indices(:MarkerIndex-1))
        ! quicksort is applied on the second part [IndexOfThreshold:nbvalues] (all values larger than the threshold)
        call quicksort(Values(MarkerIndex:), Indices(MarkerIndex:))
     END IF
  end subroutine quicksort

  END MODULE Matching_Pairs
```

Comment: The dummy argument (in your procedure shown) is allocatable, but the corresponding actual argument (in whatever calls that procedure, and which you haven’t shown) isn’t allocatable.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. You will not be able to call (or even wrap) a Fortran subroutine with allocatable dummy arguments from Python. Are you trying to do that? Or are you calling it from Fortran? Please show more code, see [mcve]. Where exactly is this subroutine getting called?

Comment: To add to what @lastchance says it is at least one of the actual arguments that correspond to the dummy arguments `mask` and `selected_transformed_mono_rays` that is not allocatable. But as Vladimir says you haven't shown us enough to say more than that. Also note real*8 is not Fortran, has never been Fortran, might not do what you expect and shouldn't be used. Learn about kinds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter

Comment: @Jack Webster - I compiled your module from your edit. It doesn't reproduce your stated error.

Comment: @lastchance It does, when compiled using f2py.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks for the explanation. I wonder if we could persuade Jack Webster just to write all his code in Fortran, rather than trying to convert it to Python!

Comment: @lastchance I would like to, however, the project I am working on is in collaboration with people who only know Python so would be a little cruel to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just found some Fortran code that would do what you need and you are trying to call it from Python using f2py as is.

That is not going to work. F2py only supports some basic subset of Fortran and does not support many modern ways how arguments can be passed. The subroutine you found uses allocatable dummy arguments. You cannot call it from Python using f2py. F2py simply does not support that.

If you want to call that code from Python using f2py, you will have to write a simpler Fortran subroutine, that will call that subroutine for you.

Also, you should only compile with f2py the code that you actually plan to call from Python. Other code that will only be called inside Fortran, should be compiled normally using a Fortran compiler into an ordinary object file and linked when creating the final library.

Comment: Thank you, this has been illuminating. I'm glad to know it is a limitation with f2py itself and not the script. I will try implementing this and will post the results of it to this question.